# Last user input keeps overwriting previous input in PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I tried to word the question as best as I could. I'm trying to create a web app that lists a few animals and then allows the user to add more to the list. That part is working just fine, however, I need the list to keep growing. What's happening right now is every time I put in a new input, the last one is overwritten.

For example, if I add "Tiger Shark" first and then add "Dolphin", "Tiger Shark" is completely replaced by "Dolphin" instead of "Dolphin" listing beneath "Tiger Shark". How do I prevent this from happening and ensure that each user input is listed beneath the previous one?

**Edited for clarification, if needed:** I'm doing this via an HTML form.

Here's my PHP code:

```
        <?php


$animal = array("Killer Whale", "Great White Shark", "Eel");

if (isset($_POST['add']))    
{ 

$add = array($_POST['animal']);
$animal = array_merge($animal, $add);

} 

foreach($animal as $a){

    echo "<li>$a</li>";

}


?>
```

And here is my HTML Form code:

```
                    <form method="post" action="Yarbrough_Chapter6Project.php" class="form">
                    <div class="form__group">
                        <input type="text"  name="animal" class="form__input" placeholder="Favorite Sea Animal">
                        <label for="animal" class="form__label">Favorite Sea Animal</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form__group">
                        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn--blue" value="Add An Animal">
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: It's not that it gets replaced, it was never there. You need *storage* to maintain it, like a database or session etc.

Comment: Try array_push($animal, $add) ;

Comment: @Arsalan  I tried that out, too, and got the same results as I did with one of the other suggestions. Got a notice for "Array to string conversion" on the echo statement and it prints "ARRAY" beneath my list and when I try to input anything via the form, it won't show up.

Comment: Can you paste your result here

Comment: You need to store the array somewhere such as a databse, also you want to stripslashes as your code can be exploited with XSS

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the element to the array using [].
`$animal[] = new_element` will always add the new_element to the end of the array.

```
<?php  

$animal = array("Killer Whale", "Great White Shark", "Eel");

if (isset($_POST['add']))    
{ 

$add = $_POST['animal'];
$animal [] = $add;

} 

foreach($animal as $a){

    echo "<li>$a</li>";

}


?>
```

Comment: So I tried this and in addition to it giving me a notice for "Array to string conversion" on the echo statement, it also shows "ARRAY" beneath my list and when I try to input anything via the form, it won't show up at all.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I edited my code. So you dont need the array() around the $_POST

Comment: I tried your new code and it's still doing the same thing. As in, it still continues to overwrite the last input.